# Parsing Python Object

Tags: python

I have a Python object:

```
<<class 'ABC'> instance: key0:b'val|key1:val1|key2:val2'>
```

I tried this:

```
print(type(var)) gives <class 'ABC'>
print(id(var)) gives id in numeric
```

where var holds above object.

How do I get value of instance from it which contains keys and values?

Comment: Uh, that'd depend on what type of object it is. What does `type(var)` give you? Alternatively, you can look at its attributes with `dir(var)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get everything, use **dir(instance)**
if you just want to get the attributes of this instance, use **instance.__dict__**
if you want to get the attributes of Class, use **instance.__class__.__dict__**

Comment: Thank you, for the help. Please, point me to some web references what format is this in Python. I have worked with lists, tuples and dictionaries but not came across this  format before.